# calculating costs and usage for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can notice that there is already a way to track cost using cost allocation tags based on each instance. However, i am planning to share my instances (s3, Ec2, lambda, API gateway, SES) which are single instances each but shared by different applications within my organization

eg:
App 1: uses the same instance of ec2, s3, lambda, api gateway, ses etc
APP 2: uses the same instance of ec2,s3....

Is there a way to track resource usage based on application where they use the shared instances or resources ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [cost allocation tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) for department/application specific resources.

Any shared resource usage based split you're going to have to work out yourself, as I don't think AWS provides this. You could possibly do it based on log file analysis. I guess you could use a query parameter or similar.

You could possibly do something with a CloudWatch custom metric. Have each application send usage data to CloudWatch, but you'd have to modify each application. Maybe you could send requests via a proxy or an API gateway.

The easy option could be to divide (shared resource cost) / (number of applications) and have them share the cost equally.